# VHDL IF statement does not work

Tags: if-statement, process, vhdl

I've got a problem with VHDL's `if` syntax.
The code looks as follows:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Shifting_zero is
    port (clk : in STD_LOGIC;
            zeros : buffer STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0));
end Shifting_zero;

architecture Behavioral of Shifting_zero is
begin

process
    begin
        if (clk'event and clk='1') then
            if (zeros='0111') then 
                zeros <= '1011';
            elsif (zeros='1011') then
                zeros <= '1101';
            elsif (zeros-'1101') then
                zeros <= '1110';
            else
                zeros <= '0111';
            end if;
        end if;
end process;

end Behavioral;
```

I receive the following errors:

> Line 15. parse error, unexpected PROCESS
>
> Line 18. parse error, unexpected TICK
>
> Line 20. parse error, unexpected TICK
>
> Line 23. parse error, unexpected TICK
>
> Line 26. parse error, unexpected END, expecting SEMICOLON
>
> Line 12. No sensitivity list and no wait in the process (warning)

I'm new to VHDL and pretty confused by those errors.

Comment: Note the difference between a character literal `'A'` and a string literal `"AAAA"`.

Comment: Did you posted the right code? Because the line numbers do not match. Even if we ignore this, there is no error in the line `process` and there is also no unexpected `END`.

Comment: `elsif (zeros-'1101') then` should read `elsif (zeros="1101") then`, right?

Answer (score -1):

OK, I found it.

I had to use " instead of ' in signals.

Comment: Not in signals, but in vectors instead of simple types.